# Laravel: Gracefully Fallback if Session Database is Not Avaiable

Tags: database, session, laravel

Is there a middware, package, or general approach for having Laravel gracefully fallback to a session-less state if the session storage engine isn't available?

That is, let's say you have you a system using the database session engine.  If that database goes down, Laravel's going to throw an exception whenever it can't connect to the database.  I'd like a way to, instead, have Laravel **not** throw an exception, and just continue on without a working session engine.

(I realize this will mean careful coding on the application level to never assume sessions are available, but a pre thank you for all the warnings)

Use Case to Correct For:

- Session storage system goes down temporarily (maintenance window, unexpected outage, etc).
- Logged in user hits a page, sees Laravel error page because session engine can't connect
- User is sad

I'd rather the user see **some** sort of normal web-page instead of a generic error message, even if that means we can't include stateful session data on the page.

Answer (score 1):

That depends, Laravel does not persistently require a session engine to work, only on pages that actually use it. So that means that a fallback would basically not help - in fact an exception is the best thing Laravel can actually do to help you here.

**Why**? Because an exception can be cought and, if that is what you want to do (even though it makes little to no sense), be ignored.

Maybe I'm understanding you wrong, what exactly do you want to fall back to?

Comment: "Laravel does not persistently require a session engine to work, only on pages that actually use it."  Are you sure that's correct?  It looks like the session middleware initiates a connection to the session storage engine. i.e. If I have sessions enabled, even if I setup a simple one line `return 'test';` route the middleware still fails with an exception, **before** I can do anything to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's really hard to imagine how could it work and what you need it for. For example when you need user to be logged to access some page what should happen if session db or whole db is down? For me the only solution is show the user info that something gone wrong because it will be hard to pretend that website is working if it's not. So application throw exception, you catch it and display error page for user (and send site admin e-mail or sms)

If you would try to pretend you probably make your users angry because they would try to log in and they wouldn't be logged in without any info, so they would try 2nd time, 3rd time and finally they would think that your site is broken and would never come back again. In my opinion it's better to tell them something is wrong and "hey, come back here in about 2 hours"

Comment: What about an application that's using an external webservice for authentication/authorization but caches data in the session to avoid saturating the web service?

Comment: @AlanStorm In this case I would try to get data from session and catch error and if one is caught, get data directly from web service. I don't think there is a package to solve this because DB can throw error in this case or session class. Probably you need to create custom session class that catches all the errors before returning any value

Comment: Laravel is not built for that type of architecture, sadly. You would have to write this functionality yourself. Though I actually can't think of an application that would have authentication done by an external webservice....

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek That's a reasonable approach, the problem is the application never gets to the routing section if it can't connect to a session. The middlware that boots during the application bootstrap requests a session connection.

Comment: @aFreshMelon Laravel actually **is** architected for this -- but it will probably require either swapping in a custom middleware session handler, or rewriting/ioc-ing the service manager.  I'm hoping someone's done this before though.